# SQL Server Output Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Environment is SQL Server 2005 
Is there a way to use named parameters when getting the output parameters of a stored proc? Currently, my knowledge of output parameters is very limited. It looks like I have to use them in order of their declaration in the stored proc. i.e., if I did `exec test @rich output,@bob output` the call would blow up. How can I have the order be arbitary? Thank you

```
create procedure test
  @ID as INT output
 ,@mark as char(20) output
as

  select @ID = 5,@mark='test'
go
declare @bob as int
declare @rich as char(20)
exec test @bob output, @rich output
select @bob,@rich
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
EXEC test @ID = @bob OUTPUT, @mark = @rich OUTPUT
```

Or, if you prefer

```
EXEC test @mark = @rich OUTPUT, @ID = @bob OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @bob as int
declare @rich as char(20)
exec test
        @mark = @rich output,
        @id = @bob output
select @bob,@rich
```

Comment: The three answers I currently see are equivalent, but putting each parameter on a separate line makes it a clearer answer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `positional` use `named parameters`

```
declare @bob as int
declare @rich as char(20)


exec test @ID = @bob output, @mark = @rich output
select @bob,@rich

exec test  @mark = @rich OUTPUT,@ID = @bob output
select @bob,@rich
```